# Guardar datos php en un txt

Tags: php

En un php tengo unos datos, como hago para guardarlos en un .txt, es decir, cuando ejecute el php, los datos también se guarden en un .txt aparte

Este es mi código

```
<?php
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $resp2 = json_decode($resp);

    foreach($resp2->orders as $orden){

        foreach($orden as $key=> $item){

           print_r($item);
           echo '***';
        }

        echo '====';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Con una simple búsqueda en google, puedes encontrar casi todo lo que necesitas. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: Deberias revisar las respuestas y si alguna te ha servido para solucionar tu problema deberias marcala como "Aceptada". En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo para la comunidad, así la pregunta no quedará eternamente pendiente.  Te recomiendo tambien que hagas el [tour] para aprender en dos minutos como funciona este sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) de este modo:

```
<?php
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $resp2 = json_decode($resp);

    $paraGuardar = '';
    foreach($resp2->orders as $orden){

        foreach($orden as $key=> $item){
           $paraGuardar .= print_r($item, true);
           print_r($item);
           echo '***';
        }
        $paraGuardar .= '====';
        echo '====';
    }

    file_put_contents('archivo.txt',$paraGuardar);
?>
```

Eso te creará el archivo **archivo.txt** en la misma carpeta desde donde se esté ejecutando el script con el resultado del [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php), al cual le hemos puesto el parámetro **true** para que no lo imprima en la salida sino que lo guarde en la variable **$paraGuardar**.

Finalmente, con el **file_put_contents**, ya fuera del bucle, creamos el archivo que contendrá el contenido de esa variable, a la cual le hemos ido concatenando los strings mediante el operador de concatenación `.=` de PHP.

Si necesitas ir agregando más cosas a ese archivo puedes hacerlo mediante el flag `FILE_APPEND` así:

```
file_put_contents('archivo.txt',$paraGuardar, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar la función `fopen()`

```
//El primer argumento es el nombre del archivo y el segundo el texto que quieres introducir en el archivo
$file = fopen('foo.txt','Hi mom');
```

El archivo se creara desde la misma ruta donde se ejecute el archivo php.